# Fit a large image in a small div

Tags: html, css, pixel, devicepixelratio

I have a conceptual question. What exactly happens when we fit a large image in the small container?

Say I am creating an HTML page to render a 100x100 px image. I have a device with a device pixel ratio of 2.

#### Case 1: Render the image inside a div of size 100x100 px

A div of height and width 100x100 px means the total device pixels available are 2x100x100 which is what exactly is needed for this image hence no problem

#### Case 2: Render the image inside a div of size 50x50 px

The total device pixel available are less than what is needed.

What happens in this case? Does the system perform some sort of downsampling?

Comment: the answer to the above large depends on how you've instructed the browser to handle such situations (rarely on its own will it down sample) Often by default the 100 x 100 image will simply be that. If you do something like hide overflow (via styles or css) it will hide anything outside of the container. With some even more clever js libs or your own efforts one can create a scheme where smaller/downsampled images can be fetched if size is a concern.

Comment: what happens? test it out yourself and see! What you can and should do is set `img { width: 100% }` you can also make use of `object-fit` to decide if a image should contain the asepct ratio, stretch/squish or should be cut off

Comment: `.image {max-width: 100%;  max-height: 100%;}` so this property `fills` the div. But what happened here? Did system sort of compressed the image? Container is defined like this `.container {width: 50px; height: 50px;}`

Comment: Are you asking what algorithms are used to either stretch or shrink an image?

Comment: I guess I went into a rabbit hole while trying to understand how different css settings affect image display. In the css setting I provided above, the image indeed must have been resampled. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Just a side point: you describe 100pxx100px as ‘device’ pixels available. Did you mean CSS pixels? On modern screens there may be several device, ie screen, pixels to one CSS pixel.

Comment: I mentioned the device pixel ratio is 2. So for 100px x 100 px css pixel image twice the number of device pixel are needed. That is what I wrote as well (2 x 100 x 100) in case 1. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t careful enough. I guess I don’t know exactly because browsers can choose what they do, but if in CSS 50px width and 50px height are specified that means there are 100 x 100 physical screen pixels available (not 2x100x100) so I guess the browser could choose to do a one to one mapping.If the images natural dimensions are 100x100. No idea whether it would or not. Hopefully someone who understands more can elucidate what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images/ the default setting for image rendering is 'auto' and the scaling algorithm is user agent dependendant i.e. no standard has been set so it may differ across browsers.

For example, in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) documentation it says:

> Since version 1.9 (Firefox 3.0), Gecko uses bilinear resampling (high
> quality).

The W3C document goes on to describe what should (preferably) happen when image rendering is specified for other values. But is is not prescriptive. Factors such as the system resources which are available are allowed to be taken into account.

So, if you have a specific system in mind you'd need to search to find what it actually uses when scaling or changing the image rendering CSS property.

Comment: I guess I know the answer but just to be double sure, when we go for resampling the sampled image can't be better than the original image, correct? It may so happen that changes are not distinguishable so they both are the same to naked eyes.

Comment: AFAIK as things are in browsers at the moment the image isn’t improved. However I see that there are services based using AI techniques now that say they improve particularly old fuzzy photos so as it’s not prescribed what algorithms should be used, maybe one day that could change.